# Using maven, how can I deploy artifacts that I have already compiled with a different version?

Tags: maven, continuous-integration

I have a continuous integration build process where each change gets compiled and deployed as a Maven snapshot. When a version is compiled and tested that people are happy with, I want to be able to deploy this to our local Maven repository with a release version.

"The Maven way" to do this would be to take the source again, set a version (versions:set etc), compile and test it all over again then deploy the resulting artifacts. As this process takes some time, I would prefer not to go through all the steps again.

Is there a way of taking the artifacts produced by the first compile step, update the version and deploy them as is without recompiling?

Comment: What you described as **The Maven Way** is luckily not the maven way. The way is using the maven-release-plugin and let maven do it's work.

Comment: In your CI environment you can configure it to support the maven release cycle which means to trigger from the build artifacts which has been defined as good and rebuild and test it and deploy the final artifacts to the appropriate repository (repo manager). Unfortunately if you like to change existing artifacts (assuming your SNAPSHOT's ) you need to rebuild them and run tests (might be turned off in this case).

Answer (score 0):

What you believe to be "Maven Way" is not necessarily true. However if you do want to deploy an arbitrary jar as a maven artifact of a different group / name / version you can do so using maven deploy plugin:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=/path/to/remote/repository -Dfile=/path/to/myjar-1.22.jar -DgroupId=somegroup -DartifactId=yourjar -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.23
```

The above example will deploy myjar-1.22 as yourjar-1.23 into remote repository.

However you should be cautious about this. Often the original version information is used inside the project itself (as a jar metadata etc)

In my opinion the best way is not to change the version number, but stick to it all the way into the software lifecycle. Utilize source control revision / build number so you always get a unique version label. For example, name your artifact `myjar-1.0.3345.23.jar` where 1.0 is your major/minor version, 3345 is your source control revision number, and 23 is the build number